# How to turn on encryption at rest in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have been tasked with ensuring our databases in SQL Server 2016 are providing "encryption at rest" does anyone have a step by step guide with regards how I go about this? (20+ dbs in place some large)

I have ran script below and it says is_encrypted = 0. all the other values are NULL. So I am guessing nothing is encrypted?

```
SELECT
    db.name,
    db.is_encrypted,
    dm.encryption_state,
    dm.percent_complete,
    dm.key_algorithm,
    dm.key_length
FROM
    sys.databases db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dm
        ON db.database_id = dm.database_id;
```

Comment: This would probably be better asked on the DBA site, but do please do a thorough web search first. I expect it is a per-database option that you can set up in SQL Server.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of this site? Many thanks

Comment: [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), but please do not post this without substantial new research. You appear to already have an account.

Comment: Thinking about it, "encryption at rest" usually just means encrypted disks. You can probably set this up at an operating system level, presumably on your RAID or mirrored disk array.

Comment: @gmisk, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde